# Is it a bad idea to create a new BlocProvider for each child inside ListView.builder?

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc

I am trying to make an app like Instagram in Flutter. The user can publish a post. The post contains number of likes, comments, ownerUsername, etc. And the post has a few interactions, it can be liked, commented, and some other specific actions for my app.

I'm handling one particular post by using a Bloc for state management and communicating with the ui and the firebase repo. And everything works good.

Now I am trying to implement a separate page with a newsfeed which would basically contain a list of posts. Now I can make a Bloc to handle the list with ListView builder, pagination, etc.
However I do not know how to handle specific interactions with each post. I cannot do them all inside one bloc, since they would share the bloc's state.

I thought of perhaps making a new BlocProvider for each child inside ListView.builder but I fear that would be a bad solution or too much resource intense?

So something like this:

```
BlocBuilder<AllPostsBloc,AllPostsState>{
builder: (context, state) {
  return ListView.builder(
    itemcount: state.allPosts.length,
    itembuilder: (context, index) {
      BlocProvider(
                    create: (context) => OnePostBloc(
                      _postRepo,
                    ),
                    child: BuildPostWidget(),
                  ),
    }
  )
 }
}
```